# cygwin rxvt without X

Tags: cygwin, xorg, rxvt

I used to be able to run rxvt.exe (not rxvt-unicode.exe) from cygwin on Windows and it would run without having cygwin's X running first.  I tried calling it via cygwin's run.exe, but that didn't matter.

Now that doesn't work (for me) anymore -- you MUST have X running now, it seems.  boo!

The error is:

`C:\>c:\apps\cygwin\bin\rxvt.exe -e /bin/bash -l`

`rxvt: can't open display as no -display option given and DISPLAY not set`

I am using the 32-bit version of Cygwin, not the 64-bit version.  The setup.exe is version 2.877 (32 bit).

The version of rxvt that comes with Cygwin is v2.7.10 (rel 26 MARCH 2003).

I am on Windows 10 if that matters.

Anyone know if there is some configuration trick?

Comment: You can try `set DISPLAY=0:0` but I can't promise that will work. FYI Use `startx` to start XWindows.

Comment: @Chloe, should have mentioned - I tried that, to no avail.  said "can't open display 0:0" or whatever.  make sense as no X is running.  I do not want the overhead of X running, anyway, I just want to run rxvt by itself, like I could do before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install an older version to get back to your desired behavior.

See this answer but ignore the parts about Postgres

https://serverfault.com/a/532412/123651

2. Install an old version if you have to. Someone maintains a historical archive of Cygwin versions.

   1. Browse the time stamp of the setup.ini file you need: ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/index.html
   2. Copy the FTP address of the folder (not index.html)
   3. Run `/setup-x86.exe -X` with the `-X` option to ignore setup signatures (they aren't archived).
   4. Paste the FTP address into the dialog to choose your download site. You will then see a snapshot of packages available during that time.

I use `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe` and it works very well without X server.

Comment: thanks!  I finally got around to trying your suggestion, and using an old fruitbat repo works.  I am again running rxvt w/o X - hurrah!  I know I'm running "old" code, but I am okay w/that.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

The RXTV version without X was retired years ago as both rxvt itself and the library to convert X call to Win call were unmaintained by long time.

The suggested terminal is Mintty; it is the default used now by Cygwin
when you need a good terminal without X Server.

Mintty works also with 64bit Cygwin, while RXVT-noX never worked there.

Comment: mintty is okay, I'm just a big fan of Rxvt.  And I always used the 32bit Cygwin on 64bit windows anyway, as that's the only way I ever got Cygwin X working, in the rare case that I did want it.  Thanks for your info, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below command. Worked for me!

> export DISPLAY=localhost:0

and to start rxvt:

> rxvt -e /bin/bash &

Comment: exporting the DISPLAY is used when running an X server.  I do not want the overhead of running an X server just to run rxvt.  Thanks anyway, though.